# How do I stop jackson's YAML writer from quoting values

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I'm working on a project to convert files from JSON to YAML. I'm using the 2.8.3 versions of the following libraries:

- jackson-core
- jackson-databind
- jackson-dataformat-yaml
- jackson-annotations

My YAML serialization code is extremely simple:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

try {
    SequenceWriter sw = writer.writeValues(System.out);
    sw.write(tree);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The YAML produced by this code looks like the following:

```
serviceType: "elasticSearch"
displayName: "Elasticsearch Service"
description: "Sample Elastic Search Service"
```

Although it is valid YAML, I don't like the double quotes around the values. You don't need them in YAML and it makes editing the resulting file more cumbersome. Does anyone know how to configure the ObjectWriter to make jackson stop encapsulating String values in quotes?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a `YAMLGenerator` feature called [`MINIMIZE_QUOTES`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.7.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLGenerator.Feature.html#MINIMIZE_QUOTES) that will turn off the quotes.

You can [`enable()`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.7.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory.html#enable(com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator.Feature)) it when creating your `YAMLFactory` like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES));
```

Comment: This solution worked. I needed to include version 1.19 of the SnakeYAML JAR in order to resolve the additional dependencies created by using the "YAMLGenerator" feature.

Answer (score 0):

Along with minimizing quotes, you can customize your yaml by [disabling](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.7.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory.html#disable(com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator.Feature)) or [enabling](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.7.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory.html#enable(com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator.Feature)) features as below:

```
YAMLFactory ymlFormatter = new YAMLFactory()
      .disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER)  //removes marker characters ---
      .enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES)
      .disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.ALWAYS_QUOTE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS)  //avoid numbers being quote
      .enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.INDENT_ARRAYS_WITH_INDICATOR);  //list array elements by prefixing hifen

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(ymlFormatter);
```